# Arithmetic overflow error converting float error in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am getting this error

> Arithmetic overflow error converting float to data type numeric

when I try to run my view but not sure what am I doing wrong with my calculation. I have researched but could not solve it so far.

Here is the line of code that is causing the error:

```
ISNULL(CAST(CAST(TOTAL_APPTS.APPT_CNT AS FLOAT) / TOTAL_RECS.PAT_CNT AS NUMERIC(3, 2)), 0) AS [CONVERSION RATE]
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your precision and scale arguments to NUMERIC are very small.  Have you tried increasing those?  Your numeric value can only handle numbers up to 9.99.

You should peruse this page:

> [decimal and numeric (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql)

It's too much to explain here, but basically the first argument (precision) is the max number of digits (in your case 3) and the second argument (scale) is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point, which always takes away from the number of digits you can have to the left of the decimal point.  So in your case, 3-2 = 1 digit allowed to the left of the decimal point, which is why your max value can only be 9.99.

Comment: i am not sure how to do that...if you please can elaborate that would be helpful.  thnx

Comment: just change 'NUMERIC(3,2)' to something like 'NUMERIC(30,15)'.

Comment: i think i got it what u were saying and that was the issue.  thnx

Comment: in .NET, the datatype was `double`. In SQL Server, it was `decimal(5,2)` and caused this error. I changed to `float` in SQL Server and works like a charm.